# JavaScript Stops Working on Pages with Question Marks in the URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I have a simple toggle script on my site that works very well, but it stops working for whatever reason on URLs with question marks in the URL. This is only a problem on Safari (works fine on Chrome and Firefox regardless of the question marks), and even then it manages to work for a couple of our Safari users. The site is hosted by a free service (rather than made from scratch by me) and I do not have control over the way the URLs are set up.

How should I proceed to solve this problem? Is there a work-around so that this does not cause an issue?

NOTE: I know next to nothing about JavaScript, so please excuse me if I am missing something obvious.

```
$(function() {
    $(".mp-toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".mp-collapse").stop().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

EDIT: I'm not sure if the question mark actually affects the script or not, but those are the only pages I've been able to recreate the issue on. Replacing the ? with %3F manually in the URL caused it to work again, but obviously this can't be asked of the members to do each time they visit a page.

http://mjskintests.proboards.com/thread/38 is an example thread from the site. The button in question is in the mini-profile (to the side of each post) that says "Show More." No error message is produced, but the content is not displayed when the button is clicked on said pages.

Comment: Probably not compatible with older safari browsers. Are you using the latest jQuery?

Comment: There's no good reason why the question mark should have any effect on Javascript. The question mark is used to separate the pathname part of the URL from parameters. The parameters can be read by a server-side script or by Javascript.

Comment: If there's something in the Javascript that uses `location.search`, that accesses the part of the URL after `?`. The snippet of JS that you posted has nothing like that.

Comment: try $(document).ready(). Also try to see in the console if there are any js errors. if you post the link to your site, we can help

Comment: @HieuLe `$(function() {})` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() {})`

Comment: @Barmar i had no idea. thanks

Comment: Members have now reported that this also does happens in Chrome.